# Checking first order differential equation: homogeneous or not.

Tags: calculus, functions

I was reading about homogeneous equations.
A function $G(x,y)$ is homogeneous of degree n if $G(tx,ty)=t^n G(x,y)$ for all $t>0$ and all $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$.

I don't get why $x+xy$, $\ln(x+y+1)$ are not homogeneous. Is it $t$ not getting cancelled out?

Comment: for $x+xy$ you get $tx+t^2xy$ which is different from $ \ne t^n(x+xy)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $ f(x,y)=x+xy$ you have:
$$f(tx,ty)=tx+t^2xy $$
$$f(tx,ty)=t(x+txy) \ne t^n(x+xy)=t^nf(x,y) $$
This is not homogeneous.

For $ g(x,y)=\ln (x+y+1)$ you have:
$$g(tx,ty)=\ln (tx+ty+1)$$
$$g(tx,ty)=\ln (t(x+y)+1)\ne t^n\ln (x+y+1)$$
You can't put the t outside the ln function. So it's not homogeneous.

Answer (score 1):

To be Homogeneous a function must pass this test:
$$f(zx,zy) = z^nf(x,y)$$
In other words,

Homogeneous is when we can take a function: $~~f(x,y)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$multiply each variable by $z$: $~~f(zx,zy)$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$and then can rearrange it to get this:    $~~z^nf(x,y)$

- **For example:** $~f(x,y)=x+xy~$

Start with: $~f(x,y) = x + xy$

Multiply each variable by $z$:   $~~f(zx,zy) = zx+z^2xy$

Which is:   $~~f(zx,zy) = z(x+zxy)$

But $~x+zxy~$ is NOT $f(x,y)$!

So $~x+xy~$ is NOT homogeneous.

- Similarly for $~\ln(x+y+1)~$.

i.e.,

Start with: $~f(x,y) = \ln(x+y+1)$

Multiply each variable by $z$:   $~~f(zx,zy) = \ln(zx+zy+1)$

Which is:   $~~f(zx,zy) \ne z^n\ln(x+y+1)~~,\text{for any}~~n$

i.e., $f(zx,zy) \ne z^nf(x,y)~~,\text{for any}~~n$

So $~\ln(x+y+1)~$ is NOT homogeneous.